# How do I open a port for a remote Postgresql connection?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, port

I am trying to set up a database on my computer that can be accessed remotely by others. I have modified my postgresql.conf by to `listening_addresses = '*'` and added `host all all 0.0.0.0/0 md5`to my pg_hba.conf file. When we try to connect to the database remotely, we get the error `psql: could not connect to server: Connection refused Is the server running on host "MYIPADDRESS" and accepting CP/IP connections on port 5432?` The port is 5432 is also closed when I got to https://www.yougetsignal.com/tools/open-ports/. How do we go about solving this problem? Let me know if I need to provide more code. Thanks in advance!

Update: Here is my log.

```
2020-06-01 12:00:09.385 EDT [13570] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2020-06-01 12:00:09.385 EDT [13570] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-06-01 12:00:09.386 EDT [13570] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

Comment: Can you try updating pb_hba.conf to ->  host all all all md5

Comment: are you sure so you removed comment from begin of line with of listening_addresses?

Comment: I figured out that the problem is because of my network settings that I do not have permission to change. I guess I will just be hosting my database online.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure so your database is running?

Do you see Postgres is process list? `ps ax|grep postgres`.

Do you see some interesting in Postgres log?

Postgres log should to contains:

```
serverlog          [----]  0 L:[  1+ 0   1/589] *(0   /50295b) 0050 0x032                                                                                              [*][X]
2020-05-29 07:45:11.931 CEST [12960] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 13beta1 on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (GCC) 10.1.1 20200507 (Red Hat 10.1.1-1), 64-bit
2020-05-29 07:45:11.933 CEST [12960] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::1", port 5432
2020-05-29 07:45:11.933 CEST [12960] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "127.0.0.1", port 5432
2020-05-29 07:45:11.959 CEST [12960] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/tmp/.s.PGSQL.5432"
```

If Postgres is running, then problem can be firewall. You should to open port 5432 for remote access.

Comment: Postgres is definitely running. I updated my original post with my log. My firewall is turned off so I don't think that is the issue.